# Permiso denegado mkdir(): Access denied php 7 - CentOS

Tags: php, apache, centos, permisos, mkdir

Muy buenos días colegas! Tengo un problema al realizar pruebas en un servidor CentOS con la función mkdir() - Aquí mi código de prueba (Aun no implemento validaciones de archivos ni seguridad):

```
//Como el elemento es un arreglo utilizamos foreach para extraer todos los 
valores
foreach($_FILES["archivos1"]['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
{
    // Validamos que el archivo exista


if($_FILES["archivos1"]["name"][$key]) {
        $filename = $_FILES["archivos1"]["name"][$key]; //Obtenemos el 
     nombre original del archivo
        $source = $_FILES["archivos1"]["tmp_name"][$key]; //Obtenemos un 
     nombre temporal del archivo

    $directorio =  'docs/'.$codigo.'/';  //Declaramos un  variable con la ruta 
   donde guardaremos los archivos

        //Validamos si la ruta de destino existe, en caso de no existir la 
   creamos
    if(!file_exists($directorio)){
            mkdir($directorio, 0770) or die("No se puede crear el directorio 
    de extracci&oacute;n"); 
    }

        $dir=opendir($directorio); //Abrimos el directorio de destino
    $target_path = $directorio.'/'.$filename; //Indicamos la ruta de 
   destino, así como el nombre del archivo

        //Movemos y validamos que el archivo se haya cargado correctamente
        //El primer campo es el origen y el segundo el destino
    if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) { 
            echo "El archivo $filename se ha almacenado en forma exitosa. 
        <br>";
            } else {    
            echo "Ha ocurrido un error, por favor inténtelo de nuevo.<br>";
        }
        closedir($dir); //Cerramos el directorio de destino
    }
}
```

Al ejecutarlo en mi localhost (xampp) funciona perfectamente, se crea la carpeta docs y se crea otra carpeta dentro de esta con los archivos enviados por el usuario a través de un input files "archivos[]" multiple.

El problema viene cuando paso a realizar la pruebas en el servidor. Cambie permisos a TODOS los directorios (0777), intente crearlos de manera recursiva, pero tengo el mismo problema de mkdir(): access denied. El usuario y grupo apache2handler: apache(48)/48 y el owner de los archivos es el root. Mi codigo esta en la ruta: var/www/html/carpeta1/carpeta2/micodigo.php

Comment: cambia el dueno de `root`a `www-data` algo como `sudo chown tu carpeta www-data:www-data` y nunca le des `777` a una carpeta

Comment: @JackNavaRow Estoy casi seguro que esa es la forma, sin embargo me indica invalid user o invalid group, en mi archivo php info indica que el usuario y grupo que ejecuta apache desde php es apache(48)/48

Comment: A ver si me aclaro. ¿ Has intentado hacer `chown apache:apache` ?

Comment: Si, el comando funciono, sin embargo no se soluciono el problema con el mkdir()

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es a la hora de determinar si la ruta existe o no y crearla y que esto se verifica con "!is_dir":

```
$dir = '/eldirectorio/quesea';
if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 755, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero de todo tienes que revisar los permisos como dicen arriba, en CentOS el usuario es `apache`. En Ubuntu y derivados de Debian es `www-data`.

En cualquiera de los casos y para que no tengas que estar cambiando los permisos constantemente lo mejor que puedes hacer es ponerte `PHP-FPM` de manera que sea el mismo usuario que estés usando para "subir" y ejecutar `PHP`.

Aquí tienes un manual sencillo de como instalar PHP-FPM en [Centos6](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-6) y [Centos7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-7)

Si una vez tengas correctos los permisos, te sigue dando errores, me comentas y miramos otras alternativas.

Adicionalmente a esto, como tambien dicen por arriba, tienes que verificar correctamente el directorio, ya que lo que estas haciendo es verificar un fichero y por tanto debes usar [`is_dir`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-dir.php) y no [`is_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-file.php)